# Geolocation not working in mac - firefox

Tags: html, macos, geolocation, mozilla

Am working on local file in mac. It is working cool in w3schools.But not with local. should we enable any services?

Comment: can you explain the steps you have taken , the code you are using and so on.This is too broad for anyone to answer

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp . I am going through this link. Tried same in local mac. It is executing the else loop which seems Geolocation not supported. Please let me know how can i run it successfully local machine. Or should i have webserver like wamp xamp etc.. ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable location access for your browser in the Mac OS system settings (Security & Privacy --> Location Services). Seems to only be required for Firefox though, Chrome works just fine without.